# setInterval() not working with src linked images in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

New coder - 1st question here.  I'm doing first free code camp project, but question is about a unrequired flourish I just want to add and learn about, it's not needed for project. I want the album covers I've linked in HTML to change every x seconds. But nothing happens yet. Images just stay static. Thanks

```
    <h2> Discography </h2>
<div class="row">
  <div id="album" class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="albums" id="album 0"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b6/Elliottsmithromancandle.jpeg" alt="1994" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 1"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e3/Elliott_Smith_%28album%29.jpg" alt="1995" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 2"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fd/Elliottsmitheitheror55.jpg" alt="1997" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 3"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/…albumcover.jpg/330px-ElliottsmithXOalbumcover.jpg" alt="1998" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 4"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/…_cover.jpg/330px-Elliott_smith_figure_8_cover.jpg" alt="2000" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 5"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8c/Elliott_smith_from_a_basement_on_the_hill_cover.jpg" alt="2004" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 6"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4e/New_Moon_%28Elliott_Smith_album%29_cover.jpg" alt="2007" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
  </div>
```

and the javascript code

```
    //Change album cover after 5 seconds - continous loop//
var Discography = document.getElementById("album");
var disc = ["album 0", "album 1", "album 2", "album 3", "album 4", "album 5", "album 6"];
var counter = 0;

function changeDisc() {
  if (counter >= disc.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
  Discography.setAttribute =disc[counter];
  counter++;

}

var myCounter = setInterval(changeDisc, 6000);

Discography.onClick = function() {

  clearInterval(Disography);

  Discography.innerHTML = "Counter stopped";

};
```

Comment: onClick !== onclick

Comment: FYI: `clearInterval(Disography);` should be `clearInterval(myCounter);`.

Comment: what is `Discography.setAttribute =disc[counter];` supposed to do? Is there some CSS that uses that? You are not using setAttribute right either.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: ids should not have whitespace in them.

Comment: An ID can't contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually setting the attribute. You are actually removing the setAttribute method and replacing it with the url. I think you want this:

```
function changeDisc() {
  if (counter >= disc.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
  Discography.setAttribute('src', disc[counter]);
  counter++;

}
```

Comment: well you uncovered one of the 4 issues that have been spotted.

Comment: haha... I stopped looking after that one :-) and it looks like we spotted it at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your code working. I don't know if this is what you wanted, but I hope it helped you.

**Assign Attributes**

```
Discography.setAttribute = disc[counter];
```

*Should be*

```
Discography.setAttribute("src", discs[counter]);
```

**Bind EventHandlers**

```
Discography.onClick = function() {
```

*Should be*

```
Discography.addEventListener("click", function () {
```

**Wrong Element**

You tried to assign the `src` attribute to the `<div id="album" class="col-lg-8">` which is a `div` and it does not have that attribute.

To fix this I added all possible album images to a `Array` and this will be assigned to a single `<img />` to get this working.

*Note that I modified some naming conventions, which I do prefer.*

**My Solution**

```js
var discs = [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b6/Elliottsmithromancandle.jpeg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e3/Elliott_Smith_%28album%29.jpg", 
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fd/Elliottsmitheitheror55.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/…albumcover.jpg/330px-ElliottsmithXOalbumcover.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/…_cover.jpg/330px-Elliott_smith_figure_8_cover.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8c/Elliott_smith_from_a_basement_on_the_hill_cover.jpg" ,
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4e/New_Moon_%28Elliott_Smith_album%29_cover.jpg",
];

var counter = 0;
var discography = document.getElementById("album");

function moveToNextDisc() {
    if (counter >= discs.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }

    discography.setAttribute("src", discs[counter]);
    counter++;
}

var interval = setInterval(moveToNextDisc, 1000);

discography.addEventListener("click", function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
    discography.innerHTML = "Counter stopped";
});
```

```html
<h2>Discography</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="albums">
            <span>
                <img id="album" alt="1994" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone - was trying something a bit out of my depth - but learnt a lot from comments. been doing this for most of the day and got nowhere. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for learning purpose, you are developing a component that:

1. changes cover every track change
2. stops when the user pauses

**Javascript** should be used for *business logic* and **html/css** as a *view reflection of the state* of the component.

So we need for an `Object` which has at least `three methods`:

- `public play` starts the player
- `public pause` pauses the player
- `private _loop` iterates through the tracks

and for a `Controller` which controls the `html view`.

```js
function Player(element, interval) {
  this.element = element;
  this.tracks = element.querySelectorAll('.albums');
  
  this.currentTrack = null;
  this.isPlaying = false;
  this._timeout = null;
  this.interval = Number(interval) || 2000;
}

Player.prototype.pause = function() {
  window.clearTimeout(this._timeout);
  this.isPlaying = false;
  
  return this;
};

Player.prototype.play = function() {
  this.isPlaying = true;
  
  return this._loop();
};

Player.prototype._loop = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self._timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    var track;
    if(self.currentTrack) {
      track = self.currentTrack.nextElementSibling;
      self.currentTrack.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    
    if(!track) {
      track = self.tracks[0];
    }
  
    track.style.opacity = 1;
    self.currentTrack = track;
    
    return self._loop();
  }, self.interval);
  
  return this;
}

/** VIEW CTRL **/
function PlayerCtrl() {
  var element = document.querySelector('#album');
  var player = new Player(element, 3000);
  
  var play = document.querySelector('#Play');
  var pause = document.querySelector('#Pause');

  play.onclick = function() {
    return player.isPlaying || player.play();
  };
  pause.onclick = function() {
    return player.isPlaying && player.pause();
  };
  
  player.play();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', PlayerCtrl);
```

```css
#album {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightcoral;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px dotted #333;
}

.albums {
  transition: 450ms opacity linear;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.albums img { max-width: 100%; }
```

```html
<button id="Play">Play</button>
<button id="Pause">Pause</button>

<hr />

<h2> Discography </h2>
<div class="row">
  <div id="album" class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="albums" id="album 0"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b6/Elliottsmithromancandle.jpeg" alt="1994" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 1"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e3/Elliott_Smith_%28album%29.jpg" alt="1995" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 2"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fd/Elliottsmitheitheror55.jpg" alt="1997" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 3"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/…albumcover.jpg/330px-ElliottsmithXOalbumcover.jpg" alt="1998" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 4"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/…_cover.jpg/330px-Elliott_smith_figure_8_cover.jpg" alt="2000" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 5"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8c/Elliott_smith_from_a_basement_on_the_hill_cover.jpg" alt="2004" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
    <div class="albums" id="album 6"> <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4e/New_Moon_%28Elliott_Smith_album%29_cover.jpg" alt="2007" class="img-responsive"></span></div>
  </div>
```